# Exponent Curve Fitting in Python

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, curve-fitting

Hello Guys I have a problem with my curve fitting, I get weird results,
below is my code:

```
x=np.array([     0.   ,    117.999,    239.843,    307.682,    478.998,
          599.465,    719.569,    839.406,    959.895,   1079.811,
         1199.307,   1319.546,   1439.448,   1560.056,   1679.475,
         1799.219,   1919.637,   2039.599,   2160.254,   2279.731,
         2399.728,   2519.749,   2639.661,   2759.891,   2879.454,
         2999.56 ,   3119.91 ,   3239.72 ,   3359.448,   3479.005,
         3599.566,   3719.498,   3839.534,   3959.571,   4079.377,
         4199.786,   4319.232,   4438.888,   4560.006,   4679.155,
         4799.745,   4919.229,   5039.53 ,   5159.228,   5279.553,
         5400.278,   5518.791,   5638.914,   5759.079,   5880.445,
         5999.498,   6119.269,   6239.705,   6359.813,   6480.192,
         6600.37 ,   6719.434,   6839.191,   6959.195,   7079.549,
         7198.495,   7318.533,   7438.822,   7559.135,   7678.648,
         7798.731,   7918.261,   8038.651,   8158.605,   8279.093,
         8398.671,   8519.004,   8638.563,   8759.005,   8878.764,
         8998.315,   9118.957,   9239.002,   9358.446,   9478.628,
         9598.738,   9719.122,   9839.224,   9958.617,  10078.85 ,
        10199.199,  10319.528,  10438.573,  10559.071,  10679.363])

y=np.array([ 121.32,  129.31,  135.11,  139.71,  147.66,  156.09,  163.03,
    170.  ,  177.08,  184.77,  191.38,  198.73,  204.51,  211.83,
    219.51,  225.53,  232.54,  238.21,  245.94,  252.82,  259.15,
    266.75,  274.07,  280.93,  287.73,  294.88,  302.89,  309.8 ,
    316.32,  322.87,  331.42,  336.98,  344.63,  348.29,  354.48,
    360.99,  368.03,  372.79,  376.91,  384.85,  388.97,  394.49,
    396.82,  401.43,  408.19,  407.6 ,  415.95,  416.8 ,  416.2 ,
    424.01,  426.7 ,  428.67,  431.59,  434.18,  437.4 ,  441.59,
    437.17,  441.6 ,  445.85,  446.06,  449.68,  449.19,  449.63,
    451.75,  451.05,  453.37,  452.8 ,  457.66,  459.33,  460.5 ,
    458.22,  461.3 ,  461.22,  462.81,  461.62,  462.99,  457.83,
    462.3 ,  464.88,  466.13,  464.85,  468.6 ,  467.93,  467.19,
    468.06,  469.46,  469.82,  471.9 ,  469.01,  469.06])
```

[image]

I am using scipy.optimize.curve_fit to do exponential fit.

```
def func(x, a, b, c):
        return a*np.exp(-b*x)+c


a0 = y.ptp()
b0 = -1/x.ptp()
c0 = y.min()
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y, p0=(a0, b0, c0), maxfev = 2000)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y, 'ko', label="Original Noised Data")
plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), 'r-', label="Fitted Curve")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

the fitting curve doesn't look nice

edit: popt and pcov values
edit2: I have modified values to look like my data is exponent

```
popt
array([  2.23557884e+06,  -1.48238130e-08,  -2.23539443e+06])

pcov
array([[  5.35480790e+16,   3.55032838e+02,  -5.35480791e+16],
       [  3.55032838e+02,   2.35392818e-12,  -3.55032839e+02],
       [ -5.35480791e+16,  -3.55032839e+02,   5.35480792e+16]])
```

Comment: Report any warnings that are generated when you run the code, and show the value of `pcov`.

Comment: You almost certainly need a better initial guess for the parameters.  The default is `p0 = (1, 1, 1)`.  Try something like `a0 = y.ptp()`, `b0 = -1/x.ptp()`, `c0 = y.min()`, and add the argument `p0=(a0, b0, c0)` to the `curve_fit` call.

Comment: I have tried, it produces just a straight line with p0 values

Comment: Whoops, I had a sign error in my suggested `p0`.  Try `a0 = -y.ptp()` and `b0 = 1/x.ptp()`.  And experiment!  The main point of my comment is the suggestion to use a better initial guess.

Comment: I fit the data to 565 different known, named equations having four or less parameters using the Differential Evolution genetic algorithm to determine initial fitting estimates each time. The best fit I could find was "y = a * exp(bx) * pow(1 + c * exp(bx), -2) + Offset" with parameters a = -1.8583081459698319E+03, b = -3.0533088033122267E-04, c =  7.7951297735918834E-01, Offset =  7.2868333959815550E+02 - you might consider a piecewise model for this data set, one equation for the lower half and one for the upper half.

Comment: is there a way automatically guess what are good starting parameters?

Comment: As I mentioned above, I use the Differential Evolution genetic algorithm for estimating initial parameters. Note that for initial parameter estimation, not all data points are needed - I use min, max and (hopefully) evenly spaced data points as this gives much better performance for the genetic algorithm. The total number of data points used for this estimation technique is the number of model parameters plus a few extra points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to fit your data with an exponential decay, which is clearly not the case. Use a bounded exponential instead, and provide better initial guess:

```
def func(x, a, b, c):
        return a*(1-np.exp(-b*x))+c

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func,x, y,p0=(600,0.1,1))
```

Comment: The parameterizations are different, but your version and the original describe the same space of possible functions.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser What does that mean?

Comment: Mainly that the original `func` *does* include bounded exponentials.  Consider (in the original) `a < 0`, `b > 0` and `c > 0`.

Comment: Yea, that´s true

Comment: Thank you very much! Its worked. I was wondering if you know better ways to guess initial parameters ?